# Active Record Pattern with Optimistic Locking - read before update vs. storing version in application?

Tags: java, activerecord, jdbc, optimistic-locking

I trying to implement the active record pattern using Java/JDBC and MySQL along with optimistic locking for concurrency handling.

Now, I have a 'version_number' field for all the records in a table which is incremented after every update.

There *seem to be* 2 strategies for implementing this:

1. The application when it requests the data it also stores the corresponding version number of each of the objects (i.e. record). On updating, the version number is 'sent down' to the data layer which is used in the UPDATE...SET...WHERE query for optimistic locking
2. The application DOES NOT store the version number, but only some parts of the object (as opposed to an entire row of data). For optimistic locking to succeed, the data layer (active record) would need to first fetch the 'row' from the DB, get version number and then fire the same UPDATE...SET...WHERE query for updating the record.

In the former there is the 'first fetch' and then an update. In the latter case you do have a 'first fetch' but *also* a fetch *right before* an update.

The question is this: *by design, which is the better approach*? Is it okay/safe/correct to have all the data, including the version number be stored in the web application's front-end (Javascript/HTML)? Or is it better to take a performance hit of a read before update?

Is there a 'right way' to implement this design? I'm not sure how current implementations of active record handle this (Ruby, Play, ActiveJDBC etc.) If I'm to implement it 'raw' in JDBC what's the right design decision in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is neither a matter of performance nor security, the two approaches are functionally different and achieve different goals.

With the first approach you are optimistically locking the row for the user's entire "think time."  If User 1 loads the screen, then User 2 makes changes, User 1's changes will fail and they will see an error that they were looking at out of date data.

With the second approach you are only protecting against interleaving writes between competing request threads.  User 1 may load a page, then User 2 makes changes, then when User 1 hits submit, their changes will go through and blow out User 2's changes.  User 1 may have made a decision based on outdate information and never know.

It's a matter of which behaviour is the one you want for your business rules, not one or the other being technically "correct."  they are both valid, they do different things.

Comment: I think there is a confusion here - I do not lock the row for the entire think time, nor does a lost update happen! I've just not made explicit the fact that I would throw an exception in case if the update failed and inform the user!! I'm not sure how either of the 2 scenarios you mention would even happen?

Comment: In scenario 1 you are optimistically locking the row for think time.  You know what the version number was when the user started thinking, and you make sure it's the same when they're done.  In scenario 2 you're checking the version number only right at the end when they submit.  It might be different from when they started thinking, hence lost update.

Comment: tl;dr option 1 is the correct way to do 'normal' optimistic locking.  option 2 results in a last-in-wins concurrency situation and really only checks for thread interleaves in the server, not user-think-interleaves.

Answer (score 1):

[ActiveJDBC](http://code.google.com/p/activejdbc/) implements version 1. With version 2, you might introduce race conditions